# wordpress custom page routing PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a custom page on a Wordpress site.

It is more or less linked to the Wordpress itself. The code is custom but I have used links to it from Wordpress Dashboard and normal pages.

The point is that now my boss wants to create a page like example.com/me/name and that should SELECT some data about the person.

Example: site.com/me/johnx

This should run something like `SELECT FROM DB WHERE first_name LIKE 'john' AND last_name LIKE '%x'` let's say.

How can I create my folder / file / function "me" so that when I type "/name" I can do an explode under it and use the last parameter to show the page?

Thank you!

**Edit:** I know about GET method.

As in example.com/me?name=johnx

But I want to know how to do it with simple slashes "/".

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a rewrite rule, which is a function called to tell Wordpress how to handle the URL's. You can find further info [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).

> add_rewrite_rule() allows you to specify additional rewrite rules for WordPress. It is most commonly used in conjunction with add_rewrite_tag() (which allows WordPress to recognize custom post/get variables).